# mysql order by field usage/limit/performance

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm currently trying to modify the selection order of some records using a javascript drag&drop mechanism.

This is the idea:

1. Once I've ordered the elements by d&d I retrieve the IDs of each element (in the right order) and I send them to php via ajax call.
2. I store the array of IDs somewhere (to develop)
3. Then, I run a query like this:

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM `items` ORDER BY field(id, ".$order.");";

   (where $order is the imploded array of IDs)

---

It works quite good but, since I never used this feature before, my doubt is:

since my IDs are strings of 16 characters, and supposing to have 200 records to order....

...Should I expect some trouble in therms of performance?

Do you see any better solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Since you still have to develop a means of storing the ID's I would suggest not doing that, but use them to fill a new column in your `items` table with a sequence of numbers representing the wanted order of the items. You can then simply order by that column in your query: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY orderColumn;";`

Comment: MySQL doesn't support function indexing and because you sort on the function FIELD() you can't make use of indexes.. So you query will be slow on larger amount off records.

Comment: "Do you see any better solution?" I think you are better of using this instead `$sql = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE id IN(".$order.") ORDER BY id";` ofcource you need to use PDO or MySQLi prepared statements to exclude SQL injection.

Comment: @ Kiko: Well, if I correctly understood what you said, updating all records is more performant than a custom select. Right? Btw, my original plan was to store the ordered id as plain text in another table (1 row).

Comment: "updating all records is more performant than a custom select. Right?" Hard to say depens on table engine being used. And the SELECT query could be running from memory (innodb buffer pool)

Comment: @ Raymond Nijland: I'm using Innodb.

Comment: Talking about performance: I'm using 16 chars IDs in order to avoid/limit cross-table duplicates but, since the ordering process doesn't affect other tables I think that it would be better using a second id field (autonumbering). Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

The comments up there made me think and I realized that this approach has a big issue.

Even considering to send the $order array only at the end of drag&drop process - I mean, push a button (unlock d&d), reorder, confirm (send&lock) - it would be however necessary to perform a custom select on every single js action comporting a refresh of the elements (view, create, rename,...). And that's pretty dumb.

So I guess that the best approach is the one suggested by Kiko, maybe with a lock system as described above to avoid an ajax call and consequent reindexing of the order field at every single move.